# Is there a way to make a chloropleth with dashed lines instead of color in Folium?

Tags: python, maps, data-visualization, folium

I am trying to make a chloropleth in Folium with two layers to compare density of two different metrics in different areas. Originally, I was going to do red for one metric and blue for another and use "purpleness" to measure overlap, but its not the prettiest map.

Is there a way I can make one layer dashed lines (where lines are closer together in areas with higher density) or another visual instead of colors? That way the overlay would make more sense. Looking through folium documentation, I did not see anything.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The approach I have adopted is to create two layers, one of which is a hatching of circles to visualize population and population density. The other is a fill by value. See [this example](https://nbviewer.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/main/examples/plugin-patterns.ipynb) for the circle hatching and [this example](https://nbviewer.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/main/examples/GeoJSON_and_choropleth.ipynb) for the fill. The actual non-employment index is used to replace population density.

```
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
import folium
from folium import plugins
from branca.colormap import linear

url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-visualization/folium/main/examples/data"
us_states = f"{url}/us-states.json"

geo_json_data = json.loads(requests.get(us_states).text)

US_Unemployment_Oct2012 = f"{url}/US_Unemployment_Oct2012.csv"
unemployment = pd.read_csv(US_Unemployment_Oct2012)

colormap = linear.YlGn_09.scale(
    unemployment.Unemployment.min(), unemployment.Unemployment.max()
)

unemployment_dict = unemployment.set_index("State")["Unemployment"]

m = folium.Map([43, -100], zoom_start=4)

def style_function(feature):
    r = unemployment_dict[feature['id']]
    #print(r)
    circles = plugins.pattern.CirclePattern(
        width=20, height=20, radius=r/2, fill_opacity=0.5, opacity=1, fill_color='#696969', color='#696969'
    )
    default_style = {
        "opacity": 1.0,
        "fillColor": "#ffff00",
        "color": "black",
        "weight": 1,
    }
    default_style["fillPattern"] = circles
    return default_style

# Adding remote GeoJSON as additional layer.
pop = folium.GeoJson(
    geo_json_data,
    name='pop',
    smooth_factor=0.5,
    style_function=style_function
).add_to(m)

unemploy = folium.GeoJson(
    geo_json_data,
    name="unemployment",
    style_function=lambda feature: {
        "fillColor": colormap(unemployment_dict[feature["id"]]),
        "color": "black",
        "weight": 1,
        #"dashArray": "5, 5",
        "fillOpacity": 0.5,
    },
).add_to(m)

m.add_child(unemploy)
m.add_child(pop)
folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
m
```

[image]

[image]